# Remove heroku toolbelt on OS X

Tags: macos, heroku, osx-mavericks, uninstallation, heroku-toolbelt

I've encountered some problems with a heroku plugin (heroku accounts) and would like to uninstall/reinstall the Heroku Toolbelt all together, but cannot find any instructions on how to do this.

Comment: The official install/uninstall guide can be found at [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Reading [this issue](https://github.com/heroku/toolbelt/issues/8) in their repository, it doesn't seem to be any official way. Here's an alternative solution:

```
rm -rf ~/.heroku
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/heroku /usr/bin/heroku
```

Comment: Will this also remove it from the $PATH? The heroku toolbelt site says (regarding the packaged installer): `The heroku command line client will be installed into /usr/local/heroku and /usr/local/heroku/bin will be added to your PATH.` I inspected the $PATH, and it wasn't there, but I'm unsure if the packaged installer added some code somewhere which will  add that to the $PATH in some cases..

Comment: The indicated routine also fails remove files like /usr/bin/foreman, which were presumably installed by heroku toolbelt. What else might be left lying around? Is there an install manifest that might be used to know with confidence what the installer changed?